# Download a File through Django-Filer instead of Redirect

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am making a file serving system that organizes different files based on categories. Once a user finds the file they need, they click a download button and it downloads it. These files are of all different kinds pdf, ai, video, etc. I was using the download attribute on HTML and it was working find locally but then I found that it didn't work when I pushed it to a hosting service.

I have read 20 different posts about using `Content-Dispostion` but I am having trouble even getting to that point. I don't have much to go on at all but below is my attempt to even access the file to be able to push it back to the user. Honestly I am just not sure of where to go from here. I just want the use to be able to click a button and the django-filer file downloads

Let me know if I need to inlclude anything else.

```
def asset_detail_view(request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Asset.objects.prefetch_related('file_set'), slug=slug)

    context = {
        'object': obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'detail_view.html', context)

def search(request):
    queryset = Asset.objects.prefetch_related('file_set').all()
    filter_set = AssetFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    return render(request, 'asset_filter_view.html', {'filter': filter_set})

def download(request, slug):
    download = File.objects.filter( asset__slug=slug ).first()
    file = FilerFile.objects.filter(id=download.file_id)
    for attr, value in file.__dict__.items():
        print(attr, value)


    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

models

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=120, blank=True, default='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente esse necessitatibus neque sequi doloribus.')
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey(File_Type, blank=False)
    description = PlaceholderField('asset_description')
    asset_category = models.ManyToManyField(Asset_Category, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    product_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    product_series = models.ManyToManyField(Series, blank=True)
    product_line = models.ManyToManyField(Line, blank=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, verbose_name='Video URL')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("assets:asset_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = FilerImageField(default=28, null=True, blank=True, related_name="image_file", verbose_name="Thumbnail")
    file = FilerFileField(null=True, blank=True, related_name="file_file")
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question. I am not sure if this is the best way, but it worked for me. 
Instead of creating a new URL to download the images I created conditional statements inside of the asset_detail_view to catch a form that was submitted through the template. I think this is what most other answers like this do, but its not well explained (in my opinion) so I was very confused where others were placing this logic. This did break the process locally because it has to open a URL and urllib does not know how to handle local paths.

HTML Template:

```
<div>
      <form>
            <input type="text" name="path" value="{{ **object url** }}" hidden>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Download">
      </form>
</div>
```

Here you will need to find a way to get the file's URL, I was using django-filer, so it was easy. I removed the additional calls I had to do to get it because it is custom to my code and will not work for others. Once submitted it was sent to the same view it was already in but now had the variable `path` attached.

views.py

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

def asset_detail_view(request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Asset.objects.prefetch_related('file_set'), slug=slug)

    context = {
        'object': obj,
    }

    if request.GET:
        query = request.GET
        filepath = query.get('path','0')
        filename = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filepath))
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

        req = Request(filepath, headers=hdr)

        with urlopen(req) as f:
            response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
            response['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
            print (response['Content-Disposition'])
            return response


    return render(request, 'detail_view.html', context)
```

the `hdr` variable was weird to me and I had to do some digging to find it. From what I understand you are essentially convincing the server that you are a browser and not a block of code trying to access the server. You can just copy and paste that.

If anyone else has anything to add or has an easier way to handle this feel free to comment or answer. Hope this helps someone else!